# compilemessages makes i18n crashes

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I have a problem when I run

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

it used to work perfectly fine but today, whenever I do it, i18n won't load on my web pages. I always get the same issue :

```
    raise ValueError('invalid token in plural form: %s' % value)
ValueError: invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION
```

I tried to empty my .po files and to rerun compilemessages, and I still get the error. I have absolutely no other clue where to look for.

Note: when I go back to any former commit, everything will run fine until I run compilemessages

Comment: Try running the command on earlier versions of your code so you can identify the breaking change. If you're using Git, the [`git bisect` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) can help with this.

Comment: Yes, I tried that before, not the problem, it really my compilemessages that might be broken, another developer run compilemessages from the same branch and didn't encounter the problem...

Answer (score 0):

in django 1.11 `makemessages -l en` creates a faulty .po file for en language
but for some other languages i have tested it works just fine.

eg. for english - wrong:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"
```

and for croatian - ok:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n"
"%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2;\n"
```

i have reported this issue here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28709